# Growth of balls vs growth of spheres in hyperbolic groups

Tags: free-groups, hyperbolic-groups, subgroup-growth

Let $G$ be a finitely-generated group equipped with a word-metric. Let $B_n$ and $S_n$ be the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$-ball and $n^{\mathrm{th}}$-sphere, respectively, with respect to the given metric. Define the following quantities for $G$.
$$b=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log\left(\left|B_n\right|\right)}{n} \text{  and  } s=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log\left(\left|S_n\right|\right)}{n}.$$
Then $s$ and $b$ are always finite and, when $G$ grows exponentially, $b$ is positive.

Assume now that $G$ is a non-elementary hyperbolic group (in the sense of Gromov). In this case by a theorem of Coornaert (Theorem 7.2 in [1]) also $s$ is positive.

When I looked at the basic example of $G=F_r$, the free group of rank $2\leq r<\infty$, an elementary calculation shows that $s=b=\log\left(2r-1\right)$. I then wondered about the equality cases of the inequality $s\leq b$ for hyperbolic groups. More precisely, my questions are:

> (1) Is it possible that $s=b$ for a finitely-generated hyperbolic group rather than free groups?

> (2) What examples we know for finitely-generated hyperbolic groups with $s<b$?

[1] *Coornaert, Michel*, [**Patterson-Sullivan measures on the boundary of a hyperbolic space in the sense of Gromov**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1993.159.241), Pac. J. Math. 159, No. 2, 241-270 (1993). [ZBL0797.20029](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0797.20029).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality $s=b$ holds for all finitely-generated infinite groups, and this does not relate to hyperbolic groups or even to exponential growth. It is a straighforward consequence of the isoperimetric inequality, by which for every finitely-generated infinite group $G$, for every $n$ one has
$$\left|B_{n}\right|\leq\left(n+1\right)\left|S_{n}\right|.$$
In fact, for non-amenable groups and in particular non-elementary hyperbolic groups, one can replace $\left(n+1\right)$ in the above inequality by a positive constant depending only on the group.

For a proof of this see for instance Chapter 12.2 and in particular Theorem 12.14 in [2].

[2] *Mann, Avinoam*, How groups grow., London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series 395. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-1-107-65750-2/pbk). ix, 199 p. (2012). [ZBL1253.20032](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1253.20032).